# Show MessageBox in a console application if user pressed a key

Tags: c#

I want to show a MessageBox in my C# console application if a user pressed a key (S for example) but without pausing the application performance.

P.S. I already added the `System.Windows.Forms` reference to show the MessageBox.

I've tried something like that:

```
do {
    while (! Console.KeyAvailable) {
        // Do something
   }       
} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.S) {
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

But it is not working as `;` is expected after `while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.S)` and not `{`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So why not adding the missing ';' character?

Comment: It makes it hard because A) you use hanging braces and B) your code is badly formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you got error

> ; expected

because your `do while(expression);` loop syntax is not correct so add semicolon(;) at the end of `do while(expression);`

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            do
            {
                while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    // Do something
                }
            } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.S);
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Test");
            }
        }
    }
```

i hope it might be helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The `do` is connected with the second `while`.

```
do{
    // do something
} while( true/false-expression );
```

and

```
while( true/false-expression){
    // do something
}
```

are proper code.

You probably have to store the result of the keypress and compare with `ConsoleKey.S` later.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for do-while expression is

```
do{
    // do something
}while(condition);
```

You missed the semi-colon. Check it above